# Prestashop, same product image URL resolving to different images for different visitors

Tags: image, url, caching, prestashop-1.5

We're using Prestashop 1.5.6.0, and something really weird is happening on a test site of ours, we have to use in a demo later today.

The following URLs:

- http://pstest.personera.com/gao/351-large_default/baby-book-girl.jpg
- http://pstest.personera.com/gao/350-large_default/baby-book-boy.jpg

are acting weird for different visitors. My colleagues in Indore, India, are seeing two different images, and we've tested on about 3 different machines at their offices. They are seeing the correct images, one of a baby boy, and one of a baby girl product cover image.

In South Africa, myself and two other colleagues are seeing the same image for both the above links. The -girl.jpg image is the same as the contents of the -boy.jpg image.

This is a really weird issue, and none of the conventional fixes work. I tried browser cache and cookie clearing. I tried 2 other machines in South Africa. I thought maybe Chrome is borked, so I tried different browsers as well as Mac OS X and Windows 7. All of them show the same image contents.

And that's not the end of it. When I add more products in Prestashop, these additional products also show the same cover graphic as for the first product in the store.

I even tried browsing through a proxy to see if I can get the correct images displaying. Nothing works.

I didn't believe my colleagues in India when they told me they see different (the correct) image content, so I TeamViewed into one of their PCs and saw that the images are displaying correctly.

The only other potential culprit I suspected is web server caching, but the thing is, the images were just uploaded minutes ago, and how on earth does the -girl.jpg image get to look the same as -boy.jpg. I tried re-uploading the images with different filenames, I even deleted the product in the eCommerce platform.

NOTHING works...any ideas?

Note: I also tried regenerating images in Prestashop...with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop has a feature to configure image quality. I turned "Use PNG only if the base image is in PNG format." off, and the problem got fixed.

I'll try using this again once we've upgraded to the latest version.

[image]